TLE6250 CAN transceiver didn't survive expected fault
I'm used to TI transceivers so I don't know if this is to be expected or not.
I have a whole bus using these transceiver (five nodes). Now, the datasheet specifies:

Suitable for 12 V and 24 V applications
Bus pins are short circuit proof to ground and battery voltage
Absolute maximum on CAN input +-40V

The bus travels around the machine with the +24 supply and the ground. Due to unexpected situation I've got an hard short between +24 and CANL. Well, 2 of 5 nodes didn't survive.
One failed with a short between CANL and ground, the other one directly between VCC and ground (spectacular failure with the package cracked open)
On the input side as protection I have, from the terminal blocks:

NUP2105L TVS (shouldn't have done a thing since it trips at at least 26V)
2× 33pF/100V common mode filter caps
A common mode choke (Würth something)
1× 15pF/50V differential mode filter caps


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Now, I don't know why the input filter was done this way since it's not a design of mine. I've always seen the filter as a single 'totem pole', not with the choke in between but I doubt that's the source of failure.
The input short was actually a sparking one (at 24V?) so it's not impossible that some boost phenomenon due to cable inductance had taken place. However the TVS should have tripped in that situation.
Any idea on what happened? I guess that the magic limitation in the transceiver didn't kick in or the 40V limit was somehow reached but I can't explain what happened (to better protect the circuit)

Instead of describing the schematic with words, please post it.

But yeah a good transceiver should survive a short against 24V so that's fishy.

SOLVED THE MYSTERY
Well, Infineon did. It was insufficient bypass capacitance; probably it needs some juice to protect correctly and during the fault it browned out

Lorenzo Marcantonio - Hi, Thanks very much for coming back with the solution. Can you add any details of what the original (failing) and the improved (working) values of bypass capacitance were, please? The application circuits in the TLE6250 datasheet show 100 nF for each of the either one or two supply pins (depending on IC version) and a 22 uF bulk capacitor shared with other devices. How does that compare with the solution you found? TY

That sounds strange - bypass caps will only hold the voltage for just so long. If the shorts last a second or so, I don't see what good caps will do? Unlike TVS which will continuously "burn away" excess voltage.

No idea... Infineon said to remove the isolation resistor and put the bypass cap in place to make it works. I'll have to try!
